# Dapper.NET and stored proc with multiple result sets

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper, multiple-resultsets

Is there any way to use Dapper.NET with stored procs that return multiple result sets?

In my case, the first result set is a single row with a single column; if it's `0` then the call was successful, and the second result set will contain that actual rows/columns of data. (and if it was non-zero, an error occured and no second result set will be provided)

Any chance to handle this with Dapper.NET? So far, I'm only ever getting back that single `0` - but nothing more.

**Update:** OK, it works fine - as long as the result set no. 2 is a single entity:

```
Dapper.SqlMapper.GridReader reader = 
    _conn.QueryMultiple("sprocname", dynParams, 
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

int status = reader.Read<int>().FirstOrDefault();
MyEntityType resultObj = reader.Read<MyEntityType>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, I have **yet another** requirement.

Dapper's multi-mapping (splitting up a single row returned from SQL Server into two separate entities) for that second result set doesn't seem to be supported as of yet (at least there doesn't seem to be an overload of `.Read<T>` that can handle multi-mapping).

How can I get split that row into two entities?

Comment: If you need to merge or "stitch together" the separate resultsets...aka collections in the dotnet code after serialization, here is a great helper method.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379155/multi-mapper-to-create-object-hierarchy/38655663#38655663

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Have you tried the `QueryMultiple` method?  It says it should:

> Execute a command that returns
>   multiple result sets, and access each
>   in turn

You'll need to add this using statement to enable QueryMultiple .

```
using Dapper; /* to add extended method QueryMultiple public static GridReader QueryMultiple(this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null); */
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from an example or a link with more detail.

Comment: Tutorial on Handling Multiple ResultSets and Multiple Mapping Using Dapper https://dzone.com/articles/tutorial-on-handling-multiple-resultsets-and-multi

Answer (score 146):

`QueryMultiple` supports the ability to deal with multiple result sets. The only design restriction we added was totally disabling buffering for the grid reader. This means the whole API is **streaming**.

In the simplest case you can use:

```
var grid = connection.QueryMultiple("select 1 select 2");
grid.Read<int>().First().IsEqualTo(1);
grid.Read<int>().First().IsEqualTo(2);
```

In the slightly more sophisticated case you can do crazy stuff like this:

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("a", 11);
p.Add("r", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

connection.Execute(@"create proc #spEcho
@a int
as 
begin

select @a Id, 'ping' Name, 1 Id, 'pong1' Name
select @a Id, 'ping' Name, 2 Id, 'pong2' Name
return @a
end");

var grid = connection.QueryMultiple("#spEcho", p, 
                                     commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

var result1 = grid.Read<dynamic, dynamic, Tuple<dynamic, dynamic>>(
                  (a, b) => Tuple.Create((object)a, (object)b)).ToList();
var result2 = grid.Read<dynamic, dynamic, Tuple<dynamic, dynamic>>(
                  (a, b) => Tuple.Create((object)a, (object)b)).ToList();

((int)(result1[0].Item1.Id)).IsEqualTo(11);
((int)(result1[0].Item2.Id)).IsEqualTo(1);

((int)(result2[0].Item1.Id)).IsEqualTo(11);
((int)(result2[0].Item2.Id)).IsEqualTo(2);

p.Get<int>("r").IsEqualTo(11);
```

You'll need to add this using statement to enable QueryMultiple .

```
using Dapper; /* to add extended method QueryMultiple public static GridReader QueryMultiple(this IDbConnection cnn, string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null); */
```

Comment: Note to future readers: QueryMultiple does not support Oracle, or rather, Oracle does not support QueryMultiple. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062569/batch-multiple-select-statements-when-calling-oracle-from-ado-net/1064692#1064692

Comment: Commiserations for getting stuck with using Oracle.

Comment: this is great! are there any caveats to look out for on this? Also is the data retrieved as one round trip?

Comment: does this support multi-threading to enable reading from the multi-reader in parallel?

Comment: Do you have to enable MultipleActiveResultSets for this to perform? Or? Maybe i just dont understand what MultipleActiveResultSets is used for :)

Answer (score 44):

Multiple result set.

```cs
var reader = conn.QueryMultiple("ProductSearch", 
                  param: new { CategoryID = 1 }, 
                  commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
var ProductListOne = reader.Read<ProuductTbl>().ToList();
var ProductListTwo = reader.Read<ProuductTbl>().ToList();
```

You'll need to add this using statement to enable QueryMultiple .

```cs
using Dapper; 
/* to add extended method QueryMultiple 
   public static GridReader QueryMultiple(
          this IDbConnection cnn, 
          string sql, 
          object param = null, 
          IDbTransaction transaction = null, 
          int? commandTimeout = null, 
          CommandType? commandType = null); 
*/
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductSearch]
    @CategoryID as int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM ProductTbl
    SELECT * FROM ProductTbl
END
```

Comment: Oracle does support QueryMultiple or QueryMultipleAsync

Comment: But how does it know which category to map it too?  Does the first time you call Read pull from the first returned result set?

Comment: @Yojin Yes, respectively

Comment: If you need to "merge" or "stitch together" the separate collections, here is a great helper method.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379155/multi-mapper-to-create-object-hierarchy/38655663#38655663

Comment: What changes dependent on whether or not you include the `.ToList()`? I see that both you and @Sam Saffron have done it in your code samples. Does it have an implication on the number of round trips, or the amount of data returned?

Comment: It didnt work for me. I have implemented dapper with .net core 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was missing one column in my DB table, one of my query is getting exception in `QueryMulitpleAsync()` due to that missing column.

I will suggest that find the one that blocking you, then compare DB column and your raw query string.