# Dapper multi-mapping - collections are empty

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm attempting to use Dapper to return a set of Shares and an associated one-to-many collection of ShareItems and ShareHistories. My Dapper call looks like this:

```
string sql =
    @"select s.Id, s.UserId, s.Name, si.ShareId as Id, si.Name as ItemName
    , sh.ShareId As Id, sh.DateShared, sh.SentTo 
    from Shares s 
    inner join ShareItems si on s.Id = si.ShareId
    inner join ShareHistory sh on s.Id = sh.ShareId
    where s.Id = @shareId";

    return conn.Query<Share, List<ShareItem>, List<ShareHistory>, Share>(
                sql,
                (share, shareItems, history) => 
                    { 
                      share.Items = shareItems; 
                      share.History = history; return share; 
                    },
                new { shareId = shareId }).Single();
```

When I run the query in SQL I get the flattened data I expect. However, when I run the code through Dapper the Items and History collections are coming back empty. I was screwing around with the splitOn parameter but after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472088/correct-use-of-multimapping-in-dapper) I now understand what splitOn is doing (this would be good to have somewhere on the Dapper site btw) and I think I'm handling that part okay. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've edited your code now for you. You should try to avoid getting scrollbars. It helps alot for others. And you're likely to get more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can populate a deep object graph from 1 row. (Unless all items are in that one row) There's a similar question: 
[Populating a list in a object with dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508322/how-do-i-map-lists-of-nested-objects-with-dapper)

Edit: There's also `QueryMultiple` - you might want to check that out. It allows the return of multiple resultsets. You could then map your entities.

[Query Multiple Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317937/dapper-net-and-stored-proc-with-multiple-result-sets)

Comment: Hm, that would be unfortunate. My current workaround is making a db call per collection, but I was hoping I could get this down to one database call in Dapper.

Comment: Have you checked out the QueryMultiple function? I've added an edit.

Comment: Does QueryMultiple execute as one db hit or one per select? If it's one per select, then I'm not gaining much over the original solution posted above. I did try it though and it does work.

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer since it's what I  ended up using. I haven't taken the opportunity to profile and see what is going to SQL, but in the interest of avoiding premature optimization this is working flawlessly.