# Multiple SQL statements in one roundtrip using Dapper.NET

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, dapper

There is a nice feature in ADO.NET that allows you to send multiple SQL statements to database in one roundtrip and receive results for all statements:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM TableA; SELECT count(*) FROM TableB;", connection);

using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    reader.Read();
    resultA = reader.GetInt32(0);
    reader.NextResult();
    reader.Read();
    resultB = reader.GetInt32(0);
}
```

Is there a similar feature in Dapper.NET?

Answer (score 108):

Yes, the Dapper `QueryMultiple` extension can do that:

```
string query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEA;
                 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEB";
using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(query, null))
{
    int countA = multi.Read<int>().Single();
    int countB = multi.Read<int>().Single();
}
```

According to [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) this is the ideal way to execute multiple queries in a single batch.

Note: Dapper creator [Sam Saffron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron) has posted a [detailed explanation with code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338193) on using `QueryMultiple` to accomplish this.

UPDATE: I add the important comment from Marc

> Note: from 1.5-ish (a little earler on the alpha builds) there is a
> ReadSingle() method that may be more convenient and efficient than
> Read().Single()

Comment: What you have here is ideal

Comment: Note: from 1.5-ish (a little earler on the alpha builds) there is a `ReadSingle<T>()` method that may be more convenient and efficient than `Read<T>().Single()`

Comment: Interesting. Need to find a bit of time to test with these new versions. Still on 1.42. Does it work with NET 4.0?

Comment: @Shil this way you reduce the number of network calls between your application server and database server. So overall response time will be better. Here i am working where we need atleast 6 result sets in a given view. So saving 5 network calls is very good

Comment: this appears to be broken in the latest version... I'm looking for a fix.

Comment: how do you add the WHERE clause for each statement?

Comment: Is there a way to have two queries in one QueryAsync call but somehow tell the database to swallow/suppress the results from the first one?  I suppose you could SELECT INTO a dummy table variable; any more elegant way?

Comment: I don't know. Did you try to post a question with the Dapper tag?  As you can see from the first comment above Dapper creators and maintainers are well known users or staff members of this site.

Answer (score 5):

```
var grid = connection.QueryMultiple("
             SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEA
             SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEB
             SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEC");
var lstResult = new List<int>();
var isNext = false;
do{
    var first2 = info.Read<int>().Single();
    lstResult.Add(first2);
    isNext=info.IsConsumed;
}
while (!isNext);
```

Comment: Thanks!! I am comparing results of many similar stored procedure. Performance tuned and not. The procs may return multiple result sets. I was not able to get all of them. I didn't see in any example the IsConsumed flag. That's why I was not able iterate over them and collect them all. Thanks for code sample