# Select Post Tags with Dapper dot net

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, orm, dapper

I have three tables in my database. Post,Tag and PostTag. Tag and Post tables has Many To Many relation and because of that PostTag table created.

My question is how can i select all posts in my table with its tags and map result to my POCO entity with Dapper.net.

Here is my poco classes. Post:

```
public class Post
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Tag:

```
public class Tag
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select all posts with all related tags to each post. I want to know how can i get a result like this ef query: _context.Posts.Include(x => x.Tags).ToList()

Answer (score 1):

Dapper is just an object mapping library, and you would have to write raw SQL or Stored Procedures by yourself. For example:

```
var sql = 
@"
select Id, Title, Body from Post where Id = @id
select Id, Title from Tag t join PostTag pt on pt.TagId = p.Id where pt.PostId = @id";

using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {id=postId}))
{
   var post = multi.Read<Post>().Single();
   var tags= multi.Read<Tag>().ToList();
   post.Tags = tags;
}
```

And similarly with mapping posts to tags.

Comment: it all comes down to whether the OP is trying to read *one* `Post`, versus *multiple* `Post`s; the latter is more complicated; for for the former - yep, that'd do it

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you would want to use Dapper's "multiple results" feature.

- https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net#multiple-results
- [Multiple SQL statements in one roundtrip using Dapper.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337468/multiple-sql-statements-in-one-roundtrip-using-dapper-net)
- [Dapper.NET and stored proc with multiple result sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317937/dapper-net-and-stored-proc-with-multiple-result-sets/6338193#6338193)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. thanks for all answers that helped me a lot. here is the full answer of my question:

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Consts.ConnectionString))
        {
            var lookup = new Dictionary<long, Post>();
            sqlConnection.Query<Post, Tag, Post>(@"
            SELECT P.*, T.*
            FROM Post P
            INNER JOIN PostTag PT ON (P.Id = PT.PostId)
            INNER JOIN Tag T ON PT.TagId = T.Id", (p, t) =>
                                                {
                                                    Post post;
                                                    if (!lookup.TryGetValue(p.Id, out post))
                                                    {
                                                        lookup.Add(p.Id, post = p);
                                                    }

                                                    if (post.Tags == null)
                                                        post.Tags = new List<Tag>();

                                                    post.Tags.Add(t);
                                                    return post;
                                                }).ToList();

            var resultList = lookup.Values;
        }
```