# Map Stored procedure result to object inside an object

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

If i have a Person class which have Dog class property  :

```
public class Person{
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public Dog Doggie {get;set;}
}
```

On a single SP call i want to populate both dog object and person object, but i cant figure out how to do that.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
 AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
      SELECT 
        Name                = p.Person_Name,
        Doggie.Name (This fails) = d.Dog_Name

      FROM My fancy join......
END
GO



  public Person GetByUid(Guid uid)
    {
        Person personToReturn;

        using (var connection = this.connectionFactory.GetOpenConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                personToReturn= connection.Query<Person>("ProcedureName",
                    new {  personUid = uid },
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).Single();
            }
            catch ()
            {
                return null;
            }

        }

    return personToReturn;
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You need to show us how you are invoking the stored procedure, and how you are mapping its returns to your Person class properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the QueryMultiple, and write 2 SELECT statements in ONE stored procedure.

Here are some helper links.

[Dapper.NET and stored proc with multiple result sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317937/dapper-net-and-stored-proc-with-multiple-result-sets/6338193#6338193)

[Multiple SQL statements in one roundtrip using Dapper.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337468/multiple-sql-statements-in-one-roundtrip-using-dapper-net)