# Insert Multiple Values and Return Multiple Values

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, dapper

I've just started using Dapper and I've run into the following problem.

I want to insert a bunch of records, and return the inserted records alongside the auto-incremented id.

Using Postgres, I want to run the equivalent of this query:

```
INSERT INTO players (name) 
VALUES ('Player1'), ('Player2'), ('Player3'), ('Player4'), ('Player5')
RETURNING id, name;
```

Using Dapper to run this query on a list of players and serialise back into a list of players (with the ids) I thought I could do this:

```
public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var players = new List<Player> { new Player { Name = "Player1" }, new Player { Name = "Player2" }, new Player { Name = "Player3" }, new Player { Name = "Player4" }, new Player { Name = "Player5" }}

connection.Query<Player>("INSERT INTO players (name) VALUES (@Name) \r\n" + 
    "RETURNING id, name, tag;", 
    players);
```

This throws the following error (it's a list of players each with a name):

```
Parameter '@Name' referenced in SQL but not found in parameter list
```

I believe that Query() may not support lists of parameters, so I tried connection.Execute() instead. Execute works, but obviously it doesn't return back the inserted players with their Ids.

It is worth noting that I can do an INSERT and RETURNING like this when I insert only one value.

Does anyone know how I can do INSERT and RETURNING for multiple values like this with Dapper?

**Update**

I have this (somewhat dirty) solution:

```
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("INSERT INTO players (name) VALUES \r\n");
        var parameters = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;

        var values = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < players.Count; i++)
        {
            var p = players[i];

            values.Add($"(@Name{i})");
            parameters[$"Name{i}"] = p.Name;
        }

        sb.Append(string.Join(", \r\n", values));

        sb.Append(" \r\nRETURNING id, name, tag;");

        // parameters = { Name1 = "Player1", Name2 = "Player2, ... etc} 

        var ret = connection.Query<Player>(sb.ToString(), parameters);
```

So building an ExpandoObject with properties from my Players and then passing that into Dapper Query(). It works, but it seems pretty dirty. Any suggestions on how to improve this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with postgresql so can't comment on that actual query, but to return multiple result sets you need to use `connection.QueryMultiple()`. Here's a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337468/multiple-sql-statements-in-one-roundtrip-using-dapper-net)

Comment: @markpsmith Thanks for your suggestion. QueryMultiple is for multiple SELECTs as it is in the linked question. I don't think it applies here.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it should be noted that passing a `List<Player>` **to the `Execute` method** as the *outermost* parameter is essentially the same as:

```
foreach(var player in players)
    connection.Execute(
         "INSERT INTO players (name) VALUES (@Name) \r\n" + 
         "RETURNING id, name, tag;", player);
```

Dapper just unrolls it for you (unless it is a very specific `async` scenario where it can pipeline the commands). Dapper *does* support list-parameter expansion, but this is for leaf-level values, and was constructed for `in (...)` usage, so the syntax would not come out quite as you want; as an example:

```
DateTime dateStart = ...
int[] custIds = ...
var orders = conn.Query<Order>(@"
    select * from Order
    where OrderDate >= @dateStart and CustomerId in @custIds",
    new { dateStart, custIds }).AsList();
```

which becomes the SQL:

```
select * from Order
where OrderDate >= @dateStart and CustomerId in (@custIds0, @custIds1, ...)
```

(depending on the number of items in the array)

Your *expected* usage is one that has been suggested and discussed quite a bit recently; *at the current time* it isn't supported - the loop unrolling only works for `Execute`, however, it is looking increasingly likely that we will add *something* here. The tricky  bit is in deciding what the correct behavior is, and whether it is *expected* that this would essentially concatenate the results of multiple separate operations.

However; to do what you want via LINQ:

```
var results = players.SelectMany(
    player => connection.Query<Player>("...", player)).AsList();
```

This is the same "unroll the loop and concatenate the results" behavior, except it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't there extra overhead in calling multiple queries like this? Can this be fixed by putting it in a transaction?

Comment: Or is there a way you would suggest that I parametrise the insert query myself and pass it into a dapper Query()?

Comment: @janderson on overhead: sure, there's a round-trip (latency) cost; the internals do a lot to reuse things like the command instance, etc. Putting it in a transaction does nothing except add a few extra levels of overhead. The fundamental issue here is that you can't blindly concatenate SQL - if it declares variables or creates temporary tables / table variables: it will break.\

Comment: @janderson the pipeline option (when available) removes the latency cost, obviously. An interesting idea is whether we could provide some expansion syntax / pattern that *would work correctly* for the multi-row case. However, I wonder whether this scenario is better served by "table valued parameters". This then immediately becomes provider / RDBMS specific, however. Does Postgres support table valued parameters? If so: we can fix it fairly trivially.

Comment: @janderson oddly enough, the problematic case for expansion syntax is usually the zero-rows case

Comment: Check the Update. I got it working that way but it seems quite hacky.