# how to write dapper in C# using Stored procedures that return multiple values?? I want to write dapper for below mentioned SP

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

```
CREATE DEFINER=`training`@`%` PROCEDURE `check_form_databases`(
in fuel_id int,   
in city_id int,  
in color_id int,  
in make_id int,  
in model_id int,  
in version_id int,  
out fuel_id_count int,  
out city_id_count int,  
out color_id_count int,  
out make_id_count int,   
out model_id_count int,  
out version_id_count int  
)  
BEGIN  
select count(CarFuelTypeId) into fuel_id_count from carfueltypes where CarFuelTypeId = fuel_id;   
select count(cities.ID) into city_id_count from cities where cities.ID = city_id;   
select count(carcolors.ID) into color_id_count from carcolors  where carcolors.ID = color_id;   
select count(carmakes.ID) into make_id_count from carmakes  where carmakes.ID = make_id;   
select count(carmodels.ID) into model_id_count from carmodels  where carmodels.ID = model_id;   
select count(carversions.ID) into version_id_count from carversions  where carversions.ID = version_id;  
END
```

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317937/dapper-net-and-stored-proc-with-multiple-result-sets) works on mySql

Comment: Please include your question in the post body, and not only in the title.

Comment: A much easier solution IMO would be to put those into variables and then select a recordset of variables into an object (replace $ with @...SO is restricting me):  select $countCarFultType = count(CarFuelTypeID)...select $countCities = count(*) ...[etc. etc.] and then end with a single one-row query with your properties: select $CountCarFuelType AS CountCarFuleType, $countCities AS CountCities.  Then just map to an object with those properties.  You wouldn't need the 'out' parameters either, cleaning that up.

Answer (score 1):

```
using(var multi = connection.QueryMultiple("check_form_databases", args,
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{
    int fuelTypes = multi.ReadSingle<int>();
    int cityCount = multi.ReadSingle<int>();
    // ...
}
```

Note: if you're reading single values, it is *usually* possible to put those into columns on a single row of a single grid, if you prefer.