# Getting MultiExec is not supported by ExecuteReader when running an SPR

Tags: c#, dapper

I wrote the following method

```
public async Task<DataTable> ExecuteProcedureToDataTableAsync(string spName, object parameters, int? commandTimeout = null, bool userPrefix = false)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
        {
            string spNameWithPrefix = GetSpNameWithPrefix(spName, userPrefix);
            var dt = new DataTable();
            _Logger.Debug($"Executing Query: [{spNameWithPrefix}], with params:[{parameters.ToJsonString()}]");
            dt.Load(await connection.ExecuteReaderAsync(spNameWithPrefix, parameters, commandTimeout: commandTimeout, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure));
            _Logger.Debug($"Completed Query To DataTable: [{spNameWithPrefix}], result columnCount:[{dt.Columns.Count}], result row count:[{dt.Rows.Count}]");
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

and invoke it like so:

```
using (var results = await ExecuteProcedureToDataTableAsync(StoredProcedureFullName, StoredProcedureParams, Timeout, userPrefix: false))
{
    ExportReport(requestModel, results);
}
```

and I get the exception:

> MultiExec is not supported by ExecuteReader

is it not supported to executeReader with spr ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple executions aren't supported by ExecuteReader. Use [QueryMultiple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6338193) instead.

Comment: but why is it multiple executions its just one spr?

Comment: @Mortalus Since I can't see your actual input, I can only guess that the way you're structuring your params is whats causing the issue. Is it IEnumerable? Refer to https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/1cd3efd89485ccd0bdcc6036eaa5a12a311189fd/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs

Comment: Thanks !  That was it .. I assumed that when receiving an object from api action it will be a dynamic object but it was not it was and array of jObjects so it failed .. I had to use dynamicParams