# MultiExec is not supported by ExecuteReader

Tags: .net, sql-server, f#, ado.net, dapper

I have the following code:

```ml
let getByIdAsync (connectionString : string) (id : int) = 
        let sql = @"SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE [Id] = @id"
        let args = [ "id" => id ]

        async {
            use connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
            do! connection.OpenAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

            try
                use! reader = connection.ExecuteReaderAsync(sql, args) |> Async.AwaitTask
                return reader |> mapRowsToRecords |> Seq.head
            with
            | e -> return Error e.Message
        }
```

This code throws `MultiExec is not supported by ExecuteReader` and I have no idea why. Other queries (like my insert for example) work just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52410794/getting-multiexec-is-not-supported-by-executereader-when-running-an-spr).

Comment: Nope, I already looked at that one, don't get it, I don't see how I got multiple exec in my case. I only have one query.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue, but you invoke `OpenAsync` and then ignore the result, meaning that `ExecuteReaderAsync` could, in principle, be started before the connection is (fully) open. You should use `do!` with `OpenAsync`.

Comment: @TomasPetricek Thank you, nice catch! I'm learning F# and was looking for a way to do `await OpenAsync()` so I was trying all sorts of hacks. Unfortunately, this does not solve the issue, but will update the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what's wrong, missing `dict` before the dictionary:

```ml
let getByIdAsync (connectionString : string) (id : int) = 
        let sql = @"SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE [Id] = @id"
        let args = dict [ "id" => id ] // added dict

        async {
            use connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
            do! connection.OpenAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

            try
                use! reader = connection.ExecuteReaderAsync(sql, args) |> Async.AwaitTask
                return reader |> mapRowsToRecords |> Seq.head
            with
            | e -> return Error e.Message
        }
```

Check [this article](https://nozzlegear.com/blog/using-dapper-with-fsharp) for more info.