# Is it possible to run any Oracle SQL Commands from C# like in SQL Developer?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got the following Requirements for a Project:

on a Website; run SQL Commands from Scripts and from a "Shell";
These Commands can be Selects, Creates, Procedures, PLSQL Packages, Views, Partitions, etc, just about everything.
They want all Messages from the Queries. The Scripts are "as is".

They will not change their Queries to fit into my program. In those Scripts can be hundreds of Table creations/alter.

I am now checking how I can do this but it´s not really clear if it´s possible.

I can see that it´s not possible to run multiple queries in a single OracleCommand, only one by one. Like: "Select * from Users; select * from Tasks;" Does not work.
And I need different Methods depending on what the Query is doing (Select vs Create).

My only ideas so far : Make an simple Parser to split everything at ";" and use those Queries in their own Commands. But then I will have to extend it if there are ";" inside the Queries.
Or: Open an Process to the SQl Shell and then read everything out it writes.

Is there anything else I can do? Any ideas what would make the least problems?

CODE:

```
using OracleConnection orclCon = new OracleConnection("");
orclCon.Open();
var query = @" create or replace view testview(ID) as select 
ID from USER";
var query2 = @" begin
               create or replace view test1(ID) as select 
              ID from USER;
              create or replace view test2(ID) as select 
              ID from USER;
                        end";
  //   OracleCommand command2 = new OracleCommand("begin " + query 
     + " end");
   OracleCommand command2 = new OracleCommand( query2 );
  orclCon.InfoMessage += new 
   OracleInfoMessageEventHandler(HandleInfo);
  command2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
 // or .Text
   command2.Connection = orclCon;
        try
        {
            // command2.ExecuteReader();
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            // command2.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (OracleException e)
        {
            return Content(e.Message.ToString() + "  \n" + 
           e.Errors[0].ToString());
        }
```

I have also tried to use execute immediate with and without '' in the query. And that´s only a Test... I have here real queries with over 400 Lines.

Error with the current Co

Blockquote

de:

```
     ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 28:
PLS-00103: Fand das Symbol "CREATE" als eines der folgenden erwartet wurde:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma...
```

Comment: yes you can run everything from c#.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch multiple select statements when calling Oracle from ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062569/batch-multiple-select-statements-when-calling-oracle-from-ado-net)

Comment: @nbk No, Begin...End does not seem to work as described in my other comment.

Comment: please show code and complete error message

Comment: I have added an Code sample and the Error

Comment: Ther es is a differ es nc es between runing two select as ndvtwo create views and I doubt very much that it will run oracle is a bit steage when it comes to multiple commands